# Are copies of Shadowrun permanently tied to a single Windows Live ID?

Tags: games-for-windows-live, shadowrun

Does anyone know if copies of Shadowrun are permanently tied to a single Windows Live ID?

I've just found a copy in my drawer and wondering if it's worth taking to the local games exchange store or if I should just toss it.

Comment: It's somewhat off topic, but to answer your subquestion: the PC game has been worth less than $1 in the U.S. since 2011 and isn't worth trading in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I own this game. The serials/keys **aren't bound** to a Windows Live ID. You can install the game on multiple computers but only use one key concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've read and heard, it's possible for other WLIDs to be used instead, so it's worth taking it down there just in case.

Comment: Ok, is there any chance it could compromise my own ID if I did so?

Comment: I very highly doubt it because the WLID is not saved on the disc.

Comment: @EarlSven - The worst case the person who buys your copy ( if the store even does so ) will be unable to register the copy they purchase.